# How to stop freeswitch by the command line?

Tags: command-line-interface, freeswitch, remote-access

`freeswitch` has it's own CLI and it is possible to shut it down with `shutdown` command issued within this CLI.

But is it possible to shut it down bu separate command, for example, by shell script?

Comment: You've only accepted 2 answers on the 7 questions you've asked that got answers. Please go back and see if you can accept some valid answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
fs_cli -x "shutdown"
```

Comment: I'm new to freeswitch and just installed it on debian (stretch). I'm unable to stop the service using this command. If I do shutdown freeswitch start with another process id.

Comment: I think that is because you start freeswitch via systemd and when systemd recognized that the process is not not there it relaunches it. If that is the case, you can start/stop freeswitch via systemd by "sudo systemctl start freeswitch" and "sudo systemctl stop freeswitch".

Answer (score 0):

```
/opt/freeswitch/bin/fs_cli --execute="show channels"
```

Comment: This will only show the current channels, not shutting down freeswitch.